# jersey 2 logging and gzip

Tags: java, rest, logging, jersey

I have the LogginFilter filter registered for the ResourceConfig.

```
// Enable logging of requests
registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()),
        true));
```

I also have the GZIPEncoding filter enabled so the response will be compressed for clients that support it.

```
// Encode gzip responses if request header supports it
EncodingFilter.enableFor(this, GZipEncoder.class);
```

But the issue now is that that logging filter is outputting the response entity compressed, ie. after the compression is applied and not before, so output look's like this making it pretty useless and impossible to see what is returned.

`INFO: 78 * Server responded with a response on thread http-bio-8443-exec-5
78 < 200
78 < Content-Type: application/json
^_^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`

I can disable the GZIPEncoder and the response is logged uncompressed but then the response entity is also sent uncompressed...

Does anyone have a suggestion how to avoid this issue and make it possible to enable server side GZIP support while at the same time debugging the response data in plain text and not compressed.

I would appreciate the assistance.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

We also had the same requirements of logging the clear text payload while compressing it. Here is how I ended up doing it.
This example is for when http client has requested Accept-Encoding: gzip.

You will have GZIPWriterFilterInterceptor class, which implements both Jersey Filter and Interceptor interfaces.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptor;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext;

import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream;
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.ENTITY_CODER)
@Compress
public class GZIPWriterFilterInterceptor implements ContainerResponseFilter, WriterInterceptor
{
/**
 * http header value for Accept-Encoding
 */
public static final String GZIP = "gzip";



protected GZIPOutputStream getGZIPOutputStream(final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException
{
    return new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream);
}

@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
        final ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
{
    final MultivaluedMap<String,String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
    //if client has requested with HttpHeader of Accept-Encoding: gzip, 
    //then do gzip encoding and put Content-Coding: gzip as part of response
    if( headers != null && headers.get(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING) != null )
    {
        for(final String header : headers.get(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING))
        {
            if(header.contains(GZIP))
            {
responseContext.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, GZIP);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(final WriterInterceptorContext context)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException
{
    if( context.getHeaders() != null && context.getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING)
            && context.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING).contains(GZIP) )
    {
        // for the response, there is only one outputstream i.e. written to by jersey after all the
        // interceptors have invoked context.proceed() in their aroundWriteTo method.
        // so when we wrap the base outputstream in a GZIPOutputStream, the response will be GZIP encoded.
        // but we also want to log the payload. Hence we use TeeOutputStream to "clone" the base outputstream.
        // As a result, jersey will write directly to TeeOutputStream, which in turn will forward the writes to
        // both GZIPOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream. We also store the ByteArrayOutputStream in context
        // so that it can be accessed by APILoggingFilter.
        final ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(getGZIPOutputStream(outputStream)
                , boas) );
        context.setProperty(Constants.ENTITY_LOGGER_PROPERTY, boas);

    }
    context.proceed();
}
}
```

Note how, we clone the output stream using Apache's TeeOutputStream.

All you need next is a Compress Annotation definition and then you can annotate your Resource method with @Compress. Also include the package name of this class in your web.xml.

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Compress 
{

}
```

Here is the relevant snippet of web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MY Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.my.gzip.logging.jaxrs.filters.package</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If you want to do payload logging, you can add another Jersey Filter/Interceptor. Here is how its aroundWriteTo method will look like.

```
    public void aroundWriteTo(final WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
{
    if (context != null)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = (ByteArrayOutputStream) context.getProperty(ENTITY_LOGGER_PROPERTY);
        if( stream == null)
        {
            //it means the GZIPWriter is not hooked in.
            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
            context.setOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(outputStream, stream) );
        }
        context.proceed();

        final String message = stream == null ? "no entity" : stream.toString();
        Logger.end(context, message);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you think. I was baffled for a while with the same issue, I thought it was a problem with the server response. The request looks just fine but the output is truncated to just a few lines. There is a constructor for the LoggingFilter where you can set the max entity size. The default buffer size is very small for the response. Pretty sure this is your issue.

https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html

```
Creates a logging filter with custom logger and entity logging turned on, but potentially limiting the size of entity to be buffered and logged.
LoggingFilter(Logger logger, int maxEntitySize)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I saw this when looking at the LoggingFilter javadoc but that is not my issue, the default of 8k is enough to at least show you the first few lines from the entity and truncate the rest and in my case it's garbage all the way, also when disabling the GZIPEncoder the whole response is printer fine so the issue it's definitely linked to the encoder. Unless someone has a solution for me, I will need to create a copy of the LoggingFilter and in change it slightly to check the header before printing and if the content is gzip/deflate to uncompress the stream before printing.